# Make ScrollPane use remaining space

Tags: javafx

I am struggling a bit with a ScrollPane I have which shares the space with a multi-line label.

The goal is simple: The label 'labelInfoBox' must be shown fully, the ScrollPane is limited to the remaining space. Practically the label takes about a third of the available space.

The issue is: When the label of the ScrollPane has a lot of text inside, the ScrollPane grows and the top label is not shown fully.
I tried setting ScrollPane's maxHeight to Infinity to first use all available space and then VBox.grow to NEVER, but this does not work, the available space is not used.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
hello-view.fxml

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.example.testscrollpane.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>

    <Label fx:id="labelInfoBox" text="InfoBox" wrapText="true" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"/>
    <ScrollPane fx:id="messageScrollBox" hbarPolicy="NEVER"
                fitToWidth="true" VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES"
                styleClass="edge-to-edge">
        <Label fx:id="messageBox" text="messageBox" wrapText="true" />
    </ScrollPane>
</VBox>

class HelloController {

    @FXML
    lateinit var labelInfoBox: Label

    @FXML
    private lateinit var messageScrollBox: ScrollPane

    @FXML
    lateinit var messageBox: Label

}

class HelloApplication : Application() {

    val messageBoxTexts = mutableListOf<String>()

    override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        val fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader(HelloApplication::class.java.getResource("hello-view.fxml"))
        val scene = Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320.0, 500.0)
        stage.title = "Hello!"
        stage.scene = scene
        stage.show()

        val helloController = fxmlLoader.getController<Any>() as HelloController
        val texts = mutableListOf<String>()
        for (i in 0..10) {
            texts.add("some text which should always be shown, line $i")
        }
        helloController.labelInfoBox.text = texts.joinToString("\n")

        for (i in 0..50) {
            messageBoxTexts.add("some text which should be scrolled, line $i")
        }
        helloController.messageBox.text = messageBoxTexts.joinToString("\n")
    }
}

fun main() {
    Application.launch(HelloApplication::class.java)
}
```

How do I make the ScrollPane use all available space, but not more?

Comment: `VBox.vgrow = “NEVER”` (which is the default) for the label, and `VBox.vgrow = “ALWAYS”` for the scroll pane.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: James_D: That does not work.

Comment: could you formulate the code in plain javafx (not overly familiar with .. kotlin?)

Comment: okay - could reproduce the issue: vbox tries to layout all nodes at their pref, if there is not enough space for all then .. the behavior is unspecified (doc talks only about excess space)? Here we can set the fixed label's min to its pref the prevent the cut-off: labelInfoBox.setPrefHeight(Region.USE_PREF_HEIGHT).

Comment: @James_D vgrow should work (at least if we look at the doc of Priority which mentions more/less space) - but vbox seems to interpret it differently, bug or feature?

Comment: kleopatra, your idea works! But I think you meant: labelInfoBox.setMinHeight(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE)

Comment: yeah, USE_PREF_SIZE is what I meant

Comment: I am questioning the use of `ScrollPane` and not `ListView`. hmmm

Comment: Also, why does it look like you are doing the controller's work in the class that extends `Application`?

Comment: @kleopatra If the `Label` is set to `vgrow = NEVER` and the `ScrollPane` is set to `vgrow = ALWAYS`, then it makes sense the `Label` would only be sized to its preferred height, and then the `ScrollPane` would take up the rest of the space. Maybe setting _both_ to `vgrow = ALWAYS` would work. Though I think the best solution is, as you mentioned, to do `label.setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE)`.

Comment: Unless you're saying the preferred height of the `Label` should be enough to show the entire text? In that case, maybe there _is_ a bug with `VBox`, or perhaps there's a "bug" in the way `Label` computes its preferred height.

Comment: @Slaw _Label with vgrow=NEVER and ScrollPane with vgrow=ALWAYS .. makes sense the Label would only be sized to its preferred height, and then the ScrollPane would take up the rest_ yes a) that's the behavior for excess space b) from the doc of Priority, I would assume the similar thingy for missing space (NEVER effective meaning don't-change-ever) but doesn't happen ;) But then could be that I mis-interpret the doc: VBox explicitly mentions _allocate additional space_ .. so my expectation for analogue behaviour for _reducing space_ might be plain wrong.

Comment: btw: Label's pref is okay (checked after the layout), copes nicely with the line-wraps .. note to self: check if the pref is correct initially